# Возрастные ограничения в России

Tags: общие-вопросы

Почитала возрастные ограничения на информацию для детей в России и ужаснулась. Согласно этого закона под запрет, по идее, должна попасть половина классической литературы, в том числе и детской. "Молодая гвардия", рассказы о военных подвигах, большинство исторических и приключенческих книг, почти вся фантастика (в том числе и мой любимый Крапивин)! Везде ведь есть сцены насилия, описана смерть и разные пороки (например, Гекльберри Финн курит). Что ж тогда детям изучать в школе и вообще читать?

Comment: Рекомендую почитать сам Закон, а не вольный пересказ журналистов и блогеров. Многие вопросы отпадут.

Comment: К сожалению ил счастью, за "вольным пересказом" у нас часто стоит опыт людей, знающих современную правоприменительную практику. А прочитать Закон, конечно, можно. И даже нужно. Вот только Дума у нас не в меру плодовита. Знать бы, о каком из последних офонаризмов идёт речь.

Comment: Например: http://www.rg.ru/2010/12/31/deti-inform-dok.html

Это хороший закон, не нойте. Гек Финн может спокойно курить (см. Глава 1, Статья 1, п. 2 - 3)

Comment: ответил....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как говорится,- "Строгость российских законов, компенсируется необязательностью их исполнения".

Это в США "Хижину дяди Тома" хотят запретить из-за того, что там часто встречается слово "негр". А у нас на книгах денег много не нахапаешь, поэтому, к счастью, наши законодатели туда суются не часто. Месяца 3 назад купил книгу Гебельса в обычном книжном магазине, а вы говорите,- "Гек Фин курит".

Ну, поставят на книги условного Пелевина маркировку "18+" с предупреждением о том, что тут есть сцены с наркотиками, так он только рад будет увеличившимся, благодаря такой рекламе продажам.

Так что опасаться не стоит. Маленькие дети будут читать, то что им предложат родители, а постарше, что захотят, и ни какие запреты им в этом не помешают.

Answer (score 2):

> Согласно этого закона

А разве не "Согласно этоМУ законУ"?

> "Строгость российских законов, компенсируется необязательностью их исполнения".

По какому правилу здесь запятая?

Comment: Инна, для подобных сообщений, никак не относящихся к сути вопроса, существуют комментарии к ответам и вопросу. У вас также есть возможность редактировать ответы и вопросы других участников.

Что касается

>"Строгость российских законов, компенсируется необязательностью их исполнения".
>>По какому правилу здесь запятая?

Она необходима для обозначения ритмики фразы. Если "запятую" в речи не поставить, фраза не будет отражать нужную мне степень противопоставления "строгость-необязательность".

Comment: Строгость российских законов, **если рассудить по чесноку**, компенсируется необязательностью их исполнения... А если без рассуждений, то запятая не лезет ни в какие ворота. (вечерний комментарий)))

Comment: >А разве не "Согласно этоМУ законУ"?    
  
Да. Но если копать вглубь, то это явление последнего века. Может потому и столь живуча эта ошибка, что за ней многовековая история русского канцелярита. Управление поменялось с родительного на дательный при боьшевиках - и, подозреваю, не без их участия.  

ЗЫ на самомедерацию г-на Марка Иза рекомендую наплевать с высокой колокольни. Ему, имхо, делать нечего - он ко всем и цепляется.

Comment: "Да. Но если копать вглубь, то это явление последнего века". Не нужно ничего копать и оправдывать всякие глупости. Нужно писать грамотно.

Comment: Гм... Знаете, в моей прошлой жизни был один интересный эпизод.  
На вахте стоял один ЛКЦ (Лицо Кавказской национальности).  
Так вот он очень любил повторять всем, кого он считал ниже себя - ну вплоть до начальника СБ - нечто наподобие: "Я тебя по-русски язык говорю. Ты на русском язык понимаешь?"   
Вы мне сейчас его очень напомнили.

Comment: "Вы мне сейчас его очень напомнили." To @ (20 Июл 22:12)behemothus.Не понял, к чему это. Вы, уважаемый бегемотус, вовсю используете правила последнего века, в том числе и то, что появилось при большевиках и с их активным участием. Что за странный аргумент?...

Answer (score 0):

А так это старый, приснопамятный 436-ФЗ...
Да согласен. Закон действительно не оговаривает процедуру признания произведения  продукцией, содержащей запрещенный материал. 
В результате производители всей новой автоматически подпадают под запретительную статью и дуют на воду. Иногда и до старых добираются. Недавние события во МХАТе тому подтверждение. Я самого спектакля не видел, но Табакову верю.

http://vmdaily.ru/news/2013/07/04/oleg-tabakov-nazval-strannoj-proverku-spektaklya-chelovek-podushka-na-nalichie-stsen-pedofilii-203501.html

Вообще закон писан словно каким-то райкинским персонажем. И такими же "персонажами"  претворяется в жизнь. Помните "А рядом Афродита - та вовсе не прикрыта"? 
http://evariel.mindmix.ru/1835-475-basnja-roditel-skoe-sobranie.zhtml

Увы, на этом форуме вести полемику по подобным вопросам невозможно даже технически .

Comment: - "Закон действительно не оговаривает процедуру признания произведения продукцией, содержащей запрещенный материал" - оговаривает. Есть такое понятие, как экспертиза.

- "Я самого спектакля не видел, но Табакову верю" - Чехова не читал, но мнение имею :-). Я, кстати тоже: спектакля не видел (и не хочу!), а Табакову вот совершенно не верю.

Я не знаю, чего вы так против. Я физически ощущаю тонны г, валящиеся на нас с экранов, пялящиеся из киосков на улице; когда-то надо хотя бы попытаться начать разгребать это.

Comment: >Я не знаю, чего вы так против  
  
Я знаю только один источник г. с экрана. Это когда показывают нашу Думу, принимающую подобные Законы. А почему я против писал. Потому, что Закон этот не работает и не будет работать так, как это якобы задумывалось. То, что написано в стартовом посте - вполне очевидная вещь.    
Повторяю, здесь не место для полемики.